# encounter null point exception when using Shared Preference

Tags: android

I have an activity which is working without operating the shared preference. After adding it, got null pointer error after clicking the button.

I think the way I am using shared preference is not correct. Anyone can help point out what is the issue? Should I new() it before using?

```
public class BanknameActivity extends Activity {

String [] bank_name;
String selected_bank_config; 
SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bankname);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    // setupActionBar();

    bank_name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bankname);

    ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bankname_listview);
    lv1.setChoiceMode(1); // CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bank_name);
    lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg)   {
                      //selected_bank_config = "Citi";
                      prefs.edit().putString(selected_bank_config, "citi").commit();                  
                      return_to_config(view);                                                  
                }
    });

}
```

Below is part of my code:

```
    public void return_to_config(View view){
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfigActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       this.finish();
}
```

Comment: You never initialise prefs. It will always be null.  Something like `prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
`

Comment: But in another activity, I also not init it, instead of edit(), I read value, it is working fine without error.

Comment: And do you know how to init it in onCreate()?

Comment: context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE); I remember I have this.. strange.. let me check again this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**you need to initialize your shared Preferences. Without initialization it will always be null.**

yo need to do following stuff:

//  mPrefs=getSharedPreferences("Preferences Name",mode);

 mPrefs=getSharedPreferences("FBPref",0);
              Editor edit=mPrefs.edit();
              edit.putString("UserName", "");
              edit.putString("UserId","");
              edit.putString("EmailId","");
              edit.commit();
```

This code is working fine.
 I hope you will appreciate it.